# How to copy odd numbered Files from one folder to another folder?

Tags: python, computer-vision

I have images with the names "image290.jpg, image291.jpg, image292.jpg,..." around 1000 images in a folder.

I want to copy all the images with odd numbers like "image291.jpg, image293.jpg, image295.jpg,..." to another folder.

How to do the stuff with python code?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import re
import shutil

base_dir= os.path.dirname(__file__)#it will fetch the path of folder in which your code file resides
input_directory_name= os.path.join(base_dir+'/all_images/')
output_directory_name= os.path.join(base_dir+'/odd_numbered_images/')
pattern = re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z]+(\d+)\.[a-zA-Z]+")
for file in os.listdir(base_dir+'/all_images/'):

if int(re.search(pattern, file).group(1))%2 != 0:
    shutil.copy(input_directory_name+ file, output_directory_name)
    print(f"copying odd numbered file {file} to "+str(output_directory_name))
else:
    print(f"skipping even numbered file {file}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution using the shutil library:

```
import os
import shutil
images = os.listdir(your_dirctory_name)
for image_name in images:
    if int(image_name[5:-4]) % 2 == 1:
        shutil.copy(your_dirctory_name + "/" + image_name, your_output_directory_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `shutil.copyfile` to move your files :

```
from shutil import copyfile
import os
import re

origin = '/you/folder/with/images'
paths = os.listdir(origin)
dst_dir = '/your/destination/dir/path'

for src in paths:
    r = re.search(r'image(\d*)\.jpg', src)

    if r and int(r.group(1)) % 2 != 0:
        copyfile(os.path.join(origin, src), os.path.join(dst_dir, r.group()))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
import re

file_names = ["image290.jpg", "image291.jpg", "image292.jpg", "image293.jpg", "image294.jpg", "image295.jpg"]

pattern = re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z]+(\d+)\.[a-zA-Z]+")

for file in file_names:
    if int(re.search(pattern, file).group(1))%2 != 0:
        print(f"copying odd numbered file {file} to blablah/bla")
    else:
        print(f"skipping even numbered file {file}")
```

Output:

```
skipping even numbered file image290.jpg
copying odd numbered file image291.jpg to blablah/bla
skipping even numbered file image292.jpg
copying odd numbered file image293.jpg to blablah/bla
skipping even numbered file image294.jpg
copying odd numbered file image295.jpg to blablah/bla
```